# How can I extend a wall outlet?

Tags: electrical, walls, receptacle

I have a interior brick wall, with wall outlet in it, I am covering the wall with 1/2" sheet rock. But I am ancoring 1x2's on the brick so I can hang the sheetrock. How would I extend the wall outlet since I will not have a 2x4 to attach the box?

Answer (score 13):

They sell extenders just for this.

[image]

They come in metal, aluminum, plastic, different thickness for many applications, single gang, double, etc...  Visit the electrical aisle of your home improvement store.

Answer (score 5):

You can also buy tabs (outlet shims) that interlock together to extend the box out. Used often for tile (I believe they are sold in the tile and electrical sections at Lowes).

[image: Outlet Shim Picture]

If what you're doing results in the outlet/switch sticking out further than the box though, then the above would be the way to go.